# scala - why do I encounter this "java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list"

Tags: scala

Here I have a piece of scala code

```
abstract class Foo[T] {
  def unit: T
  def add(x:T, y:T): T
} 
object Test extends App {
  implicit object StringFoo extends Foo[String] {
    def add(x:String, y:String): String = x concat y
    def unit: String = ""
  }

  implicit object IntFoo extends Foo[Int] {
    def add(x:Int, y:Int):Int = x+y
    def unit: Int = 0
  }

  def sum[T](xs: List[T])(implicit foo: Foo[T]):T = 
    foo.add(xs.head, sum(xs.tail))


  println(sum(List(1,2,3)))
  println(sum(List("a","b","c")))
}
```

After successful compile, I encount a "java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list"

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:337)
at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:334)
at Test$.sum(test.scala:17)
at Test$.sum(test.scala:17)
at Test$.sum(test.scala:17)
at Test$.sum(test.scala:17)
at Test$delayedInit$body.apply(test.scala:20)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
at Test$.main(test.scala:5)
at Test.main(test.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:71)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:139)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:71)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:139)
at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:45)
at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:35)
at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:45)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:74)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

However, the problem disappear if I replace the method `sum` in this way:

```
def sum[T](xs: List[T])(implicit foo: Foo[T]: T =
    if(xs.isEmpty) foo.unit
    else foo.add(xs.head, sum(xs.tail))
```

I indeed apply `sum` with non-empty List, why do I encounter that problem above?

Comment: calling head  on empty list is like accessing, first element in empty array. Is Scala the first programming language you are using ?

Answer (score 3):

You are confused because you are calling the method `sum` with a non-empty `List` but the stack trace is telling you that the list is empty. However, look more carefully at the stack, and your code.

The key is that the exception is not thrown on the first call to `sum`, but on the fourth:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:337)
at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:334)
at Test$.sum(test.scala:17)
at Test$.sum(test.scala:17)
at Test$.sum(test.scala:17)
at Test$.sum(test.scala:17)
at Test$delayedInit$body.apply(test.scala:20)
```

You have written a **recursive** method, a method that calls itself - but it calls itself again and again without ever stopping to think if it needs to continue.  Don't forget that your `List(1,2,3)` is equivalent to 
`1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil`, so `list.head` will give `1`, `list.tail` will give `2 :: 3 :: Nil`, `list.tail.head` will give `2`, etc.

Substituting the `xs` parameter once in your `sum` method gives

```
foo.add(1, sum(List(2,3))
```

and hopefully you can now see that the full method call looks like

```
foo.add(1, foo(2, foo(3, foo(Nil.head, sum(Nil.tail)))))
```

The call `Nil.head` should fail with exactly the exception you have given and adding the guard condition that you specified is exactly the right way to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

Because if xs is Nil , sum will throw exception.
Your can look Nil from [scalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Nil$)
try this code

```
def sum[T](xs: List[T])(implicit foo: Foo[T]):T =
    xs match {
        case List() =>
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty list!")
        case List(x) => x
        case x :: rest => foo.add(x, sum(rest))
}
```